# How to prove EVT using only connectivness of [a, b]?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I was just wondering if we can prove Extreme Value Theorem using just the fact that the image of a connected space is connected. I know the proof that uses the fact that [a, b] is also compact, but thats not what i am looking for.
Thanks!

Comment: Connectivity of the domain alone cannot guarantee the existence of extreme values of a continuous function. (We have a smorgasbord of counterexamples.) So, it is impossible to prove EVT without using compactness. You have to incorporate the compactness of the domain at some point of your proof.

Comment: You cannot. You need compactness because all continuous functions take connected sets to connected sets.